# Issue trying to find TOP in a query with MAX(date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, max

I am having problems figuring out how to get the correct dates out of a query. I need to pull the Oldest date for each job number but since I cannot have a Order By in my sub query I am unsure what route to go.
    --MSSQL 2016

```
Create Table #FOO
(
    Job varchar(4),
    CurrentMilestone varchar(10),
    MilestoneDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P5','ONSITE','2017-10-23');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P5','PAINT','2017-11-01');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P5','SHIP','2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P5','OFFSITE','2017-12-20');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P16','BREAK','2017-10-10');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P16','ONSITE','2017-11-11');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P16','HACK','2017-12-20');
INSERT INTO #FOO (Job,CurrentMilestone,MilestoneDate)
    VALUES ('P16','SHIP','2018-05-01');

SELECT * FROM #FOO;  

 SELECT f.Job,f.CurrentMilestone, f.MilestoneDate
    FROM (SELECT Job, MAX(MilestoneDate) as MilestoneDate 
        FROM #FOO
        GROUP BY Job
            ) a
 JOIN #FOO f ON a.Job = f.job AND a.MilestoneDate = f.MilestoneDate
 ORDER BY f.MilestoneDate ASC
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FOO') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FOO
GO
```

My return should look like:

```
Job     CurrentMilestone     MilestoneDate
P5      ONSITE               2017-10-23
P16     BREAK                2017-10-10
```

Comment: for one thing, MAX will return the latest (newest) date, not the oldest date.

Comment: Second, ***tell us what the problem you are having is***.  We cannot read your mind.

Comment: RBarry, The question is listed at the top. As you stated Yes Max returns the Max date so my return data shows the last date. I am unsure how I can get the Oldest date per Job.

Comment: RBarry is correct... if you change MAX to MIN, you get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Well, to be fair, almost... this gives you exactly what you request:
`SELECT f.Job,f.CurrentMilestone, cast(f.MilestoneDate as date) 'MilestoneDate'
    FROM (SELECT Job, MIN(MilestoneDate) as MilestoneDate 
        FROM #FOO
        GROUP BY Job
            ) a
 JOIN #FOO f ON a.Job = f.job AND a.MilestoneDate = f.MilestoneDate
 ORDER BY f.MilestoneDate DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. If there is an issue, let me know and will find the answer. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
SELECT Job, 
  CurrentMilestone,
  CAST(MilestoneDate as Date) as MilestoneDate
from (
  SELECT Job, 
   CurrentMilestone,
   MilestoneDate,
   row_number() over (partition by job order by MilestoneDate) as rnum 
  FROM #FOO) t
where t.rnum=1

Result:
Job     CurrentMilestone     MilestoneDate
P16     BREAK                2017-10-10    
P5      ONSITE               2017-10-23
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this with `TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1
   Job, 
   MilestoneDate
FROM #FOO
ORDER BY MilestoneDate ASC
```

If you are wanting it by job, use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
;with cte as(
select *
RN = row_number() over (partition by Job order by MilestoneDate asc))

select * from cte where RN = 1
```

If you are sold on `MAX()` I'd use an inner join and derived table for clarity. It's just a personal preference.

```
SELECT
   Job,
   CurrentMilestone,
   MilestoneDate
FROM #FOO F
INNER JOIN (SELECT Job, MIN(MilestoneDate) DT
            FROM #FOO
            GROUP BY Job) F2 ON F2.DT = F.MilestoneDate and F2.Job = F.Job
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has this cool way of doing this without a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES f.*
FROM #FOO f
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job ORDER BY MilestoneDate);
```